# How do I replace a field in logstash

Tags: replace, elasticsearch, filter, logstash, grok

I'm doing an insert from Logstash into ElasticSearch.  My problem is that I used a template in ES to lay out the data types, and I am sometimes getting values from Logstash that are null values (or dashes) when I've declared in ES that they should be doubles.

So sometimes, ES is getting a '-' instead of something like "2342", and it is rejecting it and causing an error.  Now, if I can replace the '-' with the word 'null', ES works fine.

How do I do this?  I assume it works with the ruby filter.  I need to be able to replace the '-' fields with null when appropriate.

**EDIT:**

I was asked for sample configs.

So, for example, say the below config is logstash, which will then send data to ES:

```
filter {
    if [type] == "transaction" {
        match => ["message", "%{BASE16FLOAT:ts}\t%{IP:orig_ip}\t%{NOTSPACE:orig_port}" ]
    }
}
```

Now my ES template is saying:

```
"transaction" : {
    "properties" :
    {
        "ts" : {
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime",
            "type" : "date"
        },
        "orig_ip" : {
            "type" : "ip"
        },
        "orig_port" : {
            "type" : "long"
        },
   }
}
```

So if I throw a data set like either of these, it passes:

```
{"ts" : "123456789.123234", "orig_ip" : "10.0.0.1", "orig_port" : "2342" }
{"ts" : "123456789.123234", "orig_ip" : "10.0.0.1", "orig_port" : null }
```

I get a success.  But, the following [obviously] fails:

```
{"ts" : "123456789.123234", "orig_ip" : "10.0.0.1", "orig_port" : "-" }
```

How can I ensure that the "-" (with quotes) gets changed to a *null*?

Comment: Can you show your logstash config, your mapping type and a sample document?

Comment: I have included a sample config.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace a string in a field in Logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092394/how-do-i-replace-a-string-in-a-field-in-logstash)

Answer (score 0):

If you amend your template by specifying `"ignore_malformed": true` in your `orig_port` `long` field, it should work.

```
"transaction" : {
    "properties" :
    {
        "ts" : {
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime",
            "type" : "date"
        },
        "orig_ip" : {
            "type" : "ip"
        },
        "orig_port" : {
            "type" : "long"
            "ignore_malformed": true     <---- add this line
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: So this will work, but I'd still like an alternative with a filter, that will change the values for me.  I'll keep looking, and if I find something, I'll post it.